# Can I use auto layout to position and resize a UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm refactoring an existing iOS app just now and trying to implement AutoLayout.

On a few of the main screens display a UIWebView that's resized depending on its content.

The view structure is simple:

```
- UIView
 |
  - UIScrollView (the full width and height of the screen)
   |
    - UIWebView (automatically resizes height based on the content loaded. Scrolling disabled)
   |
    - UIButton (40pt below the web view. Hidden in the example)
```

[image: the HTML View with a red outline to show where it cuts off]
As soon as I start to scroll down the page, the UIWebView resizes and cuts off some of the content at the bottom.

I've found a similar problem here, but with no solution.
http://raywenderlich.com/forums/posting.php?mode=reply&f=2&t=6095

My questions:

1) Is it possible to use auto layout when dynamically resizing a UIWebView like this?
2) Can you suggest what I might look at to get this working?

Comment: from the docs: `You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/)

Comment: Even when scrolling is disabled for the UIWebview?